# Parse ouput of command

Tags: linux, string, bash, parsing, extract

I am trying to extract the parameter of the output of a command. At the moment I have this:

```
ps -eaf | grep javaagent
```

The output is something like this:

```
-Dweblogic.system.BootIdentityFile=/u06/app/oracle/admin/domains/omservices/servers/profiling03/data/nodemanager/boot.properties -Dweblogic.nodemanager.ServiceEnabled=true -Dweblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerification=false -Dweblogic.ReverseDNSAllowed=false -javaagent:/u01/home/app/appdyn/AppDynamics/AppServerAgent/ver4.3.1.5/javaagent.jar -Dappdynamics.agent.applicationName=BFL_PE_Omnichannel -Dappdynamics.agent.tierName=CDLV_Profiling -Dappdynamics.agent.nodeName=profiling03 -Xms3g -Xmx3g -XX:MaxPermSize=756m -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -Xloggc:/u06/app/oracle/admin/logs/omservices/profiling03/gc.log -XX:-DisableExplicitGC -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dweblogic.MuxerClass=weblogic.socket.NIOSocketMuxer -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/u06/app/oracle/admin/logs/omservices/profiling03/dump -Dweblogic.Stdout=/u06/app/oracle/admin/logs/omservices/profiling03/profiling03.out -Dprofiling-services.configPath=/cyberbank/profiling/v2/config/ -Dorg.apache.cxf.Logger=org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Log4jLogger -Dprofiling-services.logPath=/u06/app/oracle/admin/logs/omservices/profiling03 -Duser.timezone=GMT-5 -Dweblogic.management.server=t3://ba410018-priv:4065 weblogic.Server
```

I want to extract the parameter (I am interested in this path):

```
-javaagent:/u01/home/app/appdyn/AppDynamics/AppServerAgent/ver4.3.1.5/javaagent.jar
```

I made this with the following command:

```
ps -eaf | grep javaagent | cut -d " " -f XX
```

In which "XX" is the column where XX it is. The problem of this command is that the process will not be the same always. However, javaagent will always be in the process.

In short, some command that allows me to extract the parameter javaagent in a process X.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Usually the first step in answering shell questions of the form "How do I parse the output of ...?" is to ask the alternative question "How do I get [this information] without having to parse the output of a command?".

Of course, *some* kind of parsing is almost always necessary, but if you can reduce it to a reliable split on some delimiter string, you've pretty well got the problem licked, because there are lots of ways to split a string at a delimiter. (See below for one of these.)

*NOTE:* The rest of this answer assumes a reasonably standard Linux install with `bash`, Gnu `awk` and the `ps` from package procps-ng. It could easily be adapted to other environments, but the details would make the narrative too complicated.

The `ps` command comes with a nice set of output options which make it very easy to customise the output of the command. For example, if you wanted to see all the command lines of running processes, without any other confusing data, you could try this:

```
ps -e -ops=,cmd=
```

That will print the pid and command-line of all processes on your system. (You can use `-ea` if you want to, and lots of people do. With the procps-ng version of `ps`, it makes no difference whatsoever.)

The output specification `-o` consists of a comma-separated list of fields (whose names are documented in `man ps` in the section labeled "STANDARD FORMAT SPECIFIERS"). Each field name can optionally be followed by an <kbd>=</kbd> and some text (which cannot include a comma); the text is used in the header line, which is the first line output. Using just <kbd>=</kbd> with no text signifies that the column has no header, and if no column has a header then no header line is printed. This makes "parsing" easier.

Many of the fields `ps` can print are easily parseable because they cannot contain whitespace. In fact, the manpage lists the few fields which can contain whitespace:

> The following user-defined format specifiers may contain spaces: args, cmd, comm, command, fname, ucmd, ucomm, lstart, bsdstart, start

and that list is actually much larger than the real number of different specifiers because `args` and `command` are aliases of `cmd` -- which shows the whole command line -- and `ucmd` and `ucomm` are aliases of `comm` -- which shows the name of the executable.

The fact that these fields might contain whitespace, and even newline characters, definitely complicates the parse. In the case of command-line arguments, it actually makes parsing impossible because there is no way to distinguish between a command-line argument which contains a space and two consecutive command-line arguments with a space in between them. Ideally, we would want a definitive way of extracting the command-line arguments for each process.

While we cannot get this from `ps`, we can go to the source of the information, which `ps` uses: the `/proc` filesystem. In particular, for any pid, the "file" `/proc/PID/cmdline` contains the command-line components, each terminated with a NUL bytes. For example, my `init` process looks like this:

```
$ hd /proc/1/cmdline
00000000  2f 6c 69 62 2f 73 79 73  74 65 6d 64 2f 73 79 73  |/lib/systemd/sys|
00000010  74 65 6d 64 00 2d 2d 73  79 73 74 65 6d 00 2d 2d  |temd.--system.--|
00000020  64 65 73 65 72 69 61 6c  69 7a 65 00 31 38 00     |deserialize.18.|
0000002f
```

Since a command-line option cannot contain a NUL byte, this is completely unambiguous.

We can extract all of the command lines for all running processes by simply globbing the `/proc` directory:

```
cat /proc/[1-9]*/cmdline
```

(I used `[1-9]*` instead of `*` because there are other subdirectories in the `/proc` filesystem.)

But that produces newline-separated lines of NUL-separated records, which is not the most convenient format for most utilities. (Also, it reintroduces an ambiguity because a newline could be part of an argument.) Fortunately, Gnu `awk` is happy to deal with NULs as record separators and has a regular expression matching facility. So to find all the arguments of all running processes which start with `-javaagent:`, we can use the following one-liner:

```
awk -v RS='\0' '/^-javaagent:/' /proc/[1-9]*/cmdline
```

#### Note:

There are a couple of details I skipped over in the above description. One of them is that `/proc/PID/cmdline` only contains the first 4k of the command-line. Since java invocations are frequently very long, it is possible that part of the command-line will be missing. However, since `ps` uses the `/proc` filesystem to acquire the information it shows, it will suffer from the same problem. I know of no easy way around that.

Another problem is that the data presented in `-ocmd=` can be modified by the running process, if it wants to hide or reprocess its own command-line in some way. For example, if you look at the entries for `chrome` processes, you will see that the arguments are separated with spaces rather than NULs.

Answer (score -1):

The following should work as long as there's no space in your `javaagent.jar` path :

```
ps -eaf | grep -Eo '-javaagent:[^ ]*'
```

It matches from the start of the `-javaagent` option up to the next space excluded. Using `grep`'s `-o` flag make it return only the matched section rather than whole lines.